# Distribution Estimator dependent on sample size

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I have a known distribution for my population, and it is very right skewed. Let's say Lognormal with mu = 0 and sigma = 3. The mean of this distribution is about 90, and the median is 1.

For a given sample, I am interested in knowing the ratio of values in excess of a certain threshold (lets say 90) to the total sum of the sample. For example, if I had a sample of 3 values: 3, 10, 150, then this would be 60 / (150 + 10 + 3) = 0.368.

If I sample many values and calculate this ratio, I get

```
set.seed(2021)

# large sample size
x <- rlnorm(1000000, sdlog=3)
excess <- x - 90
excess[excess < 0] = 0
sum(excess) / sum(x)
# [1] 0.8670641
```

However, with a smaller sample size (10), the average value is much lower

```
set.seed(2021)

N <- 10 # sample size
R <- 100000 # how many times to draw samples of size N
ratios <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
  x <- rlnorm(N, sdlog=3)
  excess <- x - 90
  excess[excess < 0] = 0
  
  ratios[i] <- sum(excess) / sum(x)
}
mean(ratios)
# [1] 0.2787529
```

Is there any other situation where the expected value of a estimator depends on the sample size? Is there a mathematical way to quantify this, and to estimate the expected ratio given  a known distribution and sample size?

**EDIT**

Clarifying question: Is there a method to quantify how biased the estimator of the ratio presented above is based on the sample size?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I wonder if your estimator is biased but consistent and that increasing the sample size drives the expectation toward the true value.

Comment: "Expected value of a parameter" is a contradiction in terms.  A parameter is a fixed number. An *estimator,* on the other hand, may have an expected value.  Plenty of estimators have expectations that vary with sample size.  Consider the standard deviation of a Normal sample, for instance.  However, in your example the issue is that the *sampling variance* of your estimator is *enormous.* Have you plotted the distribution of the values `x` you obtain?  Take a look.

Comment: @Dave Yes, I believe you're correct

Comment: @whuber Ah, thank you. I'm not great with the terminology. Yes, I'm aware of the sampling variance. That's the issue in the sense that it's what makes the estimator biased at low sample sizes. My question is if there's a way to quantify how this estimator depends on the sample size.

The example of standard deviation of a Normal sample is helpful, thank you.

Comment: Sampling variance is unrelated to bias.  An estimator with low sampling variance can be biased.  (Consider a constant estimator, which will be biased for any parameter value not equal to it, but which has zero sampling variance.)  An estimator with large sampling variance can be unbiased.  A standard example is the variance estimate for a Normal distribution, which is unbiased for any sample size and has relatively large sampling variance. Another is the sample mean for any heavy-tailed distribution, such as the Lognormal.

Comment: @whuber I see, thank you, embarassed to admit I wasn't familiar with sampling variance, but it seems very relevant here. I was confused because you said to plot the distribution of the values `x`. To see the sampling variance I would plot the distribution of `ratios` in my code, correct?

Comment: Right.  That will be informative in this example. ;-)  Compare the sampling distribution for various sample sizes.  Here's a quick study: `for (n in c(2, 10, 50, 250)) {
  x <- matrix(rlnorm(n * 1e5, 0, 3), n);
  y <- colSums(pmax(x - 90, 0)) / colSums(x);
  hist(y, main = bquote(.(n)))
}` To understand it, note that $90$ is the 93rd percentile of your distribution, so in small samples there is a good chance the ratio will be *zero.* That chance is 50% in samples of size $10,$ for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want an example where the expected value of an estimator depends on the sample size. Such examples certainly exist.

Consider the mean $\mu$ and an estimator $\hat\mu = \bar X + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $\bar X$ is the usual sample mean.

Then $\mathbb E\left[\hat\mu\right] = \mu + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, so the expected value of the estimator depends on the sample size.

In more generality, let $\theta$ be some parameter, let $\tilde\theta$ be an unbiased estimator of $\theta$, and let $\hat\theta = \tilde\theta + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ be some other estimator of $\theta$.

Then $\mathbb E\left[\hat\theta\right] = \theta + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, so, again, the expected value of the estimator depends on the sample size.

Comment: It's unclear how this addresses the question.  It helps (always!) to begin your answer by explaining what you think the question is asking.

Comment: This technically answers the question as I originally phrased it, so I gave (tried to give) a +1, but I originally phrased it poorly and didn't clearly ask what I actually wanted. Updated with better phrasing